# PyCharm Running Program Using Python, How To Terminate?

Tags: terminal, python, pycharm

I run my program, then when I quite PyCharm and set it to not terminate my program. But next time I want to make changes to my program when I start up PyCharm, there is no way to stop the current program. I can just quite the Python task in task Manager butt hen I need to restart my computer for the interpreter to work again. Is there a workaround or a solution to my problem?

Comment: You may wish to edit your question with a bit more detail. As-is it seems very unclear to me as to why are you running an application in PyCharm, then closing it (vs. starting it via the command line, for example) when it is apparently causing issues.

Comment: Yup, I realize my mistake. Thankyou :)

Comment: Welcome. Glad you got it sorted out. =)